# Using Winbugs plots in latex

Tags: data-visualization, winbugs, latex

I conducted a bayesian analysis and obtained some plots in winbugs. Does any one how to put the history graphs in WinBUGS in Latex? I could not save the plots as pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the .odc file as a PDF (I installed CutePDF, http://www.cutepdf.com/ to do this).

Comment: Brilliant idea @gjabel. Very much appreciated